# SQL Server 2012 - Analysis Services is not included on the "Feature Selection" screen of the installer

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssas, missing-features

According to the information on this page I was going to add Analysis Services to our instance of SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx

We ran the SQL Server installer and selected "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server". On the Feature Selection screen we only noticed the following:

```
Instance Features
    Database Engine Services
        SQL Server Replication
        Full Text.....
    Reporting Services

Shared Features
    SQL Server Data Tools
    Documentation Components
    Management Tools - Basic
    SQL Client Connectivity SDK

Redistributable Features
```

The Analysis Services feature was not in this list of choices.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Express doesn't support Analysis Services

See here what is supported by each version http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Analysis service is supported by the sql server 2012.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#SSAS

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply and link. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the express editions have Analysis Services.

Comment: SQLMenace confirmed that it's not included as part of the Express edition so we upgraded to Enterprise only to find out it was also not included as well. Feature Selection screen had the same list of features. Maybe this is a bug with the installer and a way to refresh the list is needed. We really need Analysis Services but don't know where and how to get the installer to give that choice to us. All help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @Emad There is a Business Intelligence edition now that is seperate from Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks again for all the replies. :-)